# Query with defined value after variable ${}

Tags: katalon-studio

i have script to retrieve data stored in text file, then use variable query ${} to parse the data.

example:

data kept in text file is abc

below statement will execute query `productId = 'abc'`

Now, I want to append defined value after the abc. to make the query like below:

`productId = 'abc/NDC-1111'`

**what should be the exact syntax i need to use?**

```
//Read productId
def productId = new File(RunConfiguration.getProjectDir() + "/Data Files/productId.txt")
//SQL statement
dbQuery2 = /SELECT * FROM db.t1 where productId = '${productId.text}'/
```

Comment: Hi, you've tagged this with "sql" and "postgresql", but it looks like there's another programming language involved here. Could you [edit] the tags to make sure the right people see the question who can help you?

Comment: @IMSoP i added java and groovy

Comment: Are you asking this because you face some problems with adding this text? Please provide the errors or problems you face with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
dbQuery2 = "SELECT * FROM db.t1 where productId = ${"$productId.text/NDC-1111"}"
```

Comment: Why not just `'${productId.text}/NDC-1111'`?

Comment: @user12158726 that change won't give you a prepared statement, assuming you are using Groovy's SQL, so you're open to SQL injection.

Comment: @cfrick I don't believe that will work if you're using Groovy's SQL, as it will give you single quotes inside your single quotes

Comment: Oh I did not realize `Sql` is used from what I read.  Let's hope Op actually _is_ using it or else they have an SQL injection vector...

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if it is or not, but didn't want to suggest the vulnerable answer 

Comment: i am using katalon, not sure what is behind, but it works. maybe groovy?

Comment: @user12158726 Then this question should be tagged "katalon" _only_ - without knowledge about the internals of katalon this can not be answered properly.  This here is the _groovy_ answer to the problem - it might or might not be correct for katalon.